# CSS transition doesn't work after Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I've got a script that adds an animation to elements with their individual offsets so they fade in one by one.

```
/*eslint-env es6*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    const selectCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("home-select-category-icon");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectCategory.length; i++) {
        selectCategory[i].style.animation = `fadeInCategory 2s ease-out ${ i/2+1 }s 1 forwards`;
    }

});
```

I also have some css that expands the scale of the element when you mouse over it (using :hover), and i added a transition in css too.

After everything has faded in, the transition works for a short amount of time, before it returning to no transition and the transition between the scaled and non scaled element is snappy.

I want to have a transition between the scaled element and the non scaled element, but after every fade inanimation is finished, there is no transition whatsoever.

I've looked all over to find answers and I'm stuck, I've spent ages searching to find answers and none of them seem to work for me.

[Here's the link to my code](https://codepen.io/kaffafel/pen/KKVdWoW)

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: its not clear in your question that what is the desired output?

Comment: @AtulRajput Sorry about that, im shocking at articulating. I updated my question

Comment: I think its because both your css animation and your hover transition are messing with the transform property. Try updating your `fadeInCategory` css animation (remove the transform) to something like `margin-top: -30px` @ 0% and `margin-top: 0` @ 60% and see if you get better results. margin-top also might not be the best replacement... maybe `top`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should keep your `animation` and `transition` effects on separate elements. Adding them to the same element (`.home-select-category-icon` in your case) will cause issues because the will override each other if you are animating the same property, like `transform`.

In my comment I said you can replace the `transform` with `margin-top` in your fade in animation, which would work... but I think its better to just keep them separate - even if that means creating a wrapping div or span just for animation purposes.

In your case I would move your hover transition to your `.home-select-category` element.

So add this:

```
.home-select-category {
   -webkit-transition:all 5s;
}

.home-select-category:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
}
```

and then remove those styles from the `.home-select-category-icon` styles.

Demo:

```js
/*eslint-env es6*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    const selectCategory = document.getElementsByClassName("home-select-category-icon");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectCategory.length; i++) {
        selectCategory[i].style.animation = `fadeInCategory 2s ease-out ${ i/2+1 }s 1 forwards`;
    }

});
```

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#home-select-div{
    -webkit-animation: 2s ease-out 0s 1 d;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCategory{
    0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInTitle{
    0%{opacity: 0;}
    100%{opacity: 1;}
}

html body #fb-spacer{
    height:100%;
}

*{
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #121212;
}

#fb-spacer{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#home-welcome{
    font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    padding: 100px 0px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInTitle 1.5s ease-in 0s 1 forwards;   
}

#home-select-div{
    width:80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.home-select-category-icon{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none; 
    padding: 0px 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.home-select-icon{
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
}

.home-select-category-subtitle{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
}

.home-select-category {
   -webkit-transition:all 5s;
}

.home-select-category:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
                      _       _       
                     | |     | |      
  _ __ ___   ___   __| |_   _| | ___  
 | '_ ` _ \ / _ \ / _` | | | | |/ _ \ 
 | | | | | | (_) | (_| | |_| | | (_) |
 |_| |_| |_|\___/ \__,_|\__,_|_|\___/ 
                                      
                                      
-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Modulo HTPC</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/efa620f8a0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script async src="home.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-spacer">
            <div id="home-welcome">
                <h1>Welcome back</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="home-select-div">
                <button class="home-select-category-icon">
                    <div id="home-select-game" class="home-select-category">
                        <i class="fas fa-gamepad home-select-icon"></i>
                        <p class="home-select-category-subtitle">Gaming</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button class="home-select-category-icon">
                    <div id="home-select-movie" class="home-select-category">
                        <i class="fas fa-video home-select-icon"></i>
                        <p class="home-select-category-subtitle">Movie</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button class="home-select-category-icon">
                    <div id="home-select-music" class="home-select-category">
                        <i class="fas fa-music home-select-icon"></i>
                        <p class="home-select-category-subtitle">Music</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <button class="home-select-category-icon">
                    <div id="home-select-exit" class="home-select-category">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt home-select-icon"></i>
                        <p class="home-select-category-subtitle">Exit</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this work perfectly. I was about to go insane lol